# DataGridView records disappear after closing form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is not bound to a table in a database. The datagridview is being populated by the contents of a drop down list and a text box on a button click. I want to prevent the records from being deleted everytime I close the form. Is there a way for the records in the datagridview to be saved without having to create a database table?

Below is my code:

```
private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.dgInsertedInfo.Rows.Add(ddlVendorID.Text, txtDate.Text);
}
```

Comment: you have to persist it in some other way like saving in a text file. But if you have very large records, this is not efficient. Or do you really need to dispose it by closing the form or hiding it would be enough? And what is the problem with saving it on the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many options. Here is a simple solution that uses [XML serialization](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ay27kt9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Note that it makes a few assumptions:

- The data all are strings
- The DataGridView already has all the columns

To save the other data types you should create a serializable structure!

```
private void saveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();

    foreach(DataGridViewRow row  in dgInsertedInfo.Rows)
    {
       List<string> rowData = new List<string>();
       foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
           rowData.Add(cell.FormattedValue.ToString());
       data.Add(rowData);
    }

    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
    using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(yourFileName))
    {
        xs.Serialize(tw, data);
        tw.Close();
    }
}

private void loadButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<List<string>> data = new List<List<string>>();

    XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(data.GetType());
    using (TextReader tr = new StreamReader(yourFileName))
         data = (List<List<string>>) xs.Deserialize(tr);

    foreach (List<string> rowData in data)
        dgInsertedInfo.Rows.Add(rowData.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your OWN class and save it as a setting-property.

[image: property setting]

Class Settings:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class Settings
    {
        private ObservableCollection DataGridItemsProp;
        public ObservableCollection DataGridItems
        {
             get { return DataGridItemsProp; }
             set { DataGridItemsProp = value; }
        }
    }
}
```

Get and save your setting:

```
//get settings
var datagrid = Properties.Settings.Default.UserSettings;

//save settings
Properties.Settings.Default.UserSettings= datagrid;
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```